# udev rules stopped working after random reboot on debian

Tags: udev

I have 9 udev rules for network interface in `/etc/udev/rules.d/hostname_netinterface.rules` file. This is a virtual machine on esxi. I made this file after the interfaces kept shifting after reboots. It was working for some time but now suddenly after a few months another reboot and the same file that was working just suddenly stopped.

File Format looks like this: there is 9 of them.

```
file: /etc/udev/rules.d/hostname_netinterface.rules

KERNEL=="eth*", SYSFS{address}=="22:22:33:44:33:22", NAME="eth0"
KERNEL=="eth*", SYSFS{address}=="22:22:33:44:33:44", NAME="eth1"
KERNEL=="eth*", SYSFS{address}=="22:22:33:44:33:55", NAME="eth2"
 and so on up until eth9
```

I checked syslog and it says this for each line 1-9:

```
unknown key 'SYSFS{address}' in /etc/udev/rules.d/010_netinterfaces.rules:9
```

This must have broken because of unnatended security updates in Debian because this was working for several months.
Please help.

Comment: You do know that one thing computers suck at is being random :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why it was working but if you do this to check your udev for network interfaces.

```
user@host:~$ udevadm info -a -p /sys/class/net/eth0 |grep address
ATTR{address}=="22:22:33:44:33:22"
```

Notice how the address has `ATTR` before it and not `SYSFS`. 
I changed my file around replacing `SYSFS` with `ATTR` and it fixed it.

```
KERNEL=="eth*", ATTR{address}=="22:22:33:44:33:22", NAME="eth0"
```

This was working before, so my assumption is " unnatended upgrades " made a change in udev.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue. In my case I was pushing my .rules file from local to the target. When udev rules are reloaded it was working. But, when I reboot the target, rules were not getting applied. Soln: Re-build your image with updated .rules file. This worked for me.
Seems like udev daemon verifies for a build time checksum for .rules file. Hence, it was not loading the new rules file that was locally modified and pushed.